# No background sync after restarting browser

Tags: service-worker, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps, background-sync

I am implementing PWA with a service worker, utilizing Background Sync and IndexedDB in uploading images while user is offline.

So it is working! While offline on uploading an image, nativeFile is pushed to IndexedDB and a unique tag is registered for background sync. After bringing up network to online, the background sync called my function to upload the file from indexedDB to server. That happens when my browser is open.

HOWEVER, in the scenario where uploading while being offline. Then restart the browser and go online, no background sync is triggered after opening it.

Is this how supposed background sync will work? only when browser is open? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Background sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) should work even if the browser was closed. It was clearly stated in the sample app provided in the documentation. Check [these steps](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync#the_solution) to understand more about how the background sync works. After the sending the data (the moment after you hit the send button). You have the option to either close the browser while still be able to send the data.

Comment: There are some things that can only be done while your app is in foreground, like registering to a sync event for example. Maybe your 'sync' event handler is doing something that is not allowed in background. Can you share your sync handler code?